# Category based layered navigation position order change - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation, navigation

May I know how can I change the order of layered navigation `attribute` (same attribute) position based on `category`

**I have 2 category:**

**Eg:**

1. Shirt,
2. T-shirt

**Attribute :**

Color

`Shirt category:` layer navigation display the color attribute position in 0

`T-shirt Category:`layer navigation display the color attribute position in  2